# Once a coin name has been created is there anything stopping another coin being created with the exact same name?

Tags: altcoin

With the advent of a service like coingen.io, there's going to be A LOT of altcoins flooding the market.

So once a coin name has been created is there anything stopping another coin being created with the exact same name?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, only problem will be people getting confused and technical problems if altcoins run on similar ports and work similarly. Name is completely cosmetic.